# Generalizing / simplifying multipolygon in PostGIS without missing polygons?

Tags: postgis, polygon, topology, simplify, generalization

By following the rules from [this site](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiSimplifyWithTopologyExt), I got the output but some polygons do not come within the simplified polygon. I think the problem is with topology.

Is there any solution?

[image: example]

Comment: what tolerance did you use for `st_simplifyPreserveTopology`

Comment: I used the same 10000 meters for st_simplifypreserveTopology. And also  I reduced that to 5000 and rechecked that but no improvement.

Comment: I'd start at 500 and go from there - really depends on the projection and how big your map is

Comment: I tried that now and got some improvement in orientation of lines  but still the polygons are not simplified.

Comment: what projection are you using? try 0.005

Comment: From the beginning I am using epsg4326

Comment: then your tolerance is in degrees, so go with a very small number

Comment: If I want to have it in meters, then the projection should be changed to the country's projection let's say epsg is 31467 i.e for Germany. If i go with a small number then there become no use of simplification that's why.

Comment: I have reduced the tolerance up to 100 and checked the simplification after the projection was changed to 31467 from 4326 but still a polygon is not simplified